# Unable to Login through Automation(Cypress) to app, while the credentails are true. It allows manual login but unable to login through Cypress

Tags: javascript, dom, automation, cypress, webautomation

I am trying to login to this page  https://eddui--preprod2.sandbox.my.site.com/s/scplogin?language=en_US&redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Ficampp.edd.ca.gov%2Fhome%2Fcaeddicamext_uiostgrf_1%2F0oa6gj2jlz4J3AlIE1d7%2Faln6gj88wtdBQHuBn1d7

and trying to login through the DOM element's Email and Password field but Cypress is unable to log in the credentials are all ok. Its displaying the your credentials are wrong but when I manually login, it logins successfully

Here is the code:

```js
  describe('Authentication flow', function() {
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.fixture('user.json').as('user');
});
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
  })
  it('Redirects to login', () => {
cy.visit('https://eddui--preprod2.sandbox.my.site.com/s/scplogin?language=en_US&redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Ficampp.edd.ca.gov%2Fhome%2Fcaeddicamext_uiostgrf_1%2F0oa6gj2jlz4J3AlIE1d7%2Faln6gj88wtdBQHuBn1d7');
  //cy.get('#CustomerPortalTemplate').first('div').first('div').first('div').first('div').first('.cb-section_row').first().first().first().first().first().first('div').first().first().first('.right-section').first().find('.language-link.forget-pwd').click().wait(10000)
  cy.get('#CustomerPortalTemplate').first('div').first('div').first('div').first('div').first('.cb-section_row').first().first().first().first().first().first('div').first().first().first('.right-section').first().find('.form-control.edd-input').eq(0).focus().type('PERF_SCPEXTA_19408@scpperf.com').wait(3000);
  cy.get('#CustomerPortalTemplate').first('div').first('div').first('div').first('div').first('.cb-section_row').first().first().first().first().first().first('div').first().first().first('.right-section').first().find('[name="Login password"]').eq(0).invoke('attr', 'value', 'California@').wait(3000);
  cy.get('#CustomerPortalTemplate').first('div').first('div').first('div').first('div').first('.cb-section_row').first().first().first().first().first().first('div').first().first().first('.right-section').first().find('[type="submit"]').click()
   });
```

Comment: `name="Login password"`

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  @ArleighHix

Comment: That is the actual `name` attribute of the element you seek, not `input[name="password"]`